# Checking table content before adding new content

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to create a table that stores users.
What I was able to build was a table where you can add and remove some users.
Now I am trying to check the content before adding a row.
If I execute the function my table will grow exponentially instead of checking the content before adding the new user.

```
  //    push on the button excecutes addRow
function addRow(){

    var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var surName=document.getElementById("surName").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    compareRows(document.getElementById('Gebruikers'));

}

//first i want to compare content of rows vs the inputfields

function compareRows(){
    var table=document.getElementById("Gebruikers");
    var rowCount=table.rows.length;

//check first cell of the row. when it is the same as firstName check surName
        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
            var row=table.rows[i];
            var vCheck=row.cells[0];
            if(vCheck===firstName) {

//check second cell of the row. when it is the same as surName check email              
                for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
                    var row=table.rows[i];
                    var vCheck=row.cells[1];
                    if (aCheck===surName) {

//check third cell of the row. when it is the same as email show prompt that use allready exists.
//if email doesnt exist check next row  
                        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
                            var row=table.rows[i];
                            var eCheck=row.cells[2];
                            if (eCheck===email) {
                                prompt ("Deze gebruiker bestaat al!")
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };

//when all rows have been checked for input execute insertRow function
            } else {
            insertRow(firstName, surName, email);
            };
        } 
};


function insertRow(firstName, surName, email)
{
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var table = document.getElementById("Gebruikers");

    table.appendChild(row);

    row.appendChild(createTd(firstName));
    row.appendChild(createTd(surName));
    row.appendChild(createTd(email));

    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var remove=document.createElement("input");
    remove.type="checkbox";
    remove.name="chkbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(remove);
}

function createTd(text) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerText = text;
    return td;
}


function deleteRow(){
    var table=document.getElementById("Gebruikers");
    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
            var row=table.rows[i];
            var chkbox=row.cells[3].childNodes[0];
                if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <table class="table" id="Users">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td>e-mail</td>
            <td>remove</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>

    <form>
        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="firstName"> <br>
        Surname:<br>
        <input type="text" id="surName"> <br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="text" id="email"> <br>
    </form>

    <br>

    <button id="addButton" onclick="addRow()">add</button>
    <button id="deleteButton" onclick="deleteRow()">delete</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see you still have call to insertRow function inside loop body, which mean that it will add as many rows as there is already in table if they don't match. What i would do is add some kind of variable which would be changed if comparing the rows will return true.

```
var temp = 0; if(all_rows=true){temp++;}
```

and after the loop i would add:

```
if(temp > 0) {insertRow();}
```

So it would be something like this:

```
function compareRows(){
    var table=document.getElementById("Gebruikers");
    var rowCount=table.rows.length;
var temp = 0;
//check first cell of the row. when it is the same as firstName check surName
        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
            var row=table.rows[i];
            var vCheck=row.cells[0];
            if(vCheck===firstName) {

//check second cell of the row. when it is the same as surName check email              
                for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
                    var row=table.rows[i];
                    var vCheck=row.cells[1];
                    if (aCheck===surName) {

//check third cell of the row. when it is the same as email show prompt that use allready exists.
//if email doesnt exist check next row  
                        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
                            var row=table.rows[i];
                            var eCheck=row.cells[2];
                            if (eCheck===email) {
                                prompt ("Deze gebruiker bestaat al!")
                                temp++;
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };

//when all rows have been checked for input execute insertRow function
            } else {

            };

        } 
        if(temp > 0)
        {
         insertRow(firstName, surName, email);
         }
};
```

Comment: When i take it out of the loop, it wont execute the insertRow function. When i keep it in the loop it will add exponantiolly. the content of the cells is always: "[object HTMLInputElement]".

Comment: well actually you can probably do all of this an easier way. Basically two loops should be enought first you do a loop over all rows and inside this loop if value of first checked element is duplicated then you loop trought the rest of row elements to make sure that all elements in row are duplicated. if so you set a flag(variable) to 1 so it won't add a row, otherwise it will add a row. Could you give us the html code on which you work, what kind of elements do you work with. As for cell value it is becouse the value you have in cell is input so you should call cell.val() or something.

Comment: var vCheck=row.cells[0].value;
doesn't change it sadly

Comment: Could you tell me what js framework do you exactly use?